# boost ptree failure with reverse iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, iterator, reverse-iterator

The following code works properly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::property_tree;

int main()
{
    ptree root;
    root.put("building.age", "42");
    root.put("company.age", "32");
    root.put("street.age", "19");

    ptree attached_node;
    attached_node.put("confirmed","yes");
    attached_node.put("approved","yes");

    for(auto it=root.begin();it!=root.end();++it)
    {
        std::cout
                << (it->first)
                << ": "
                << (it->second.get<std::string>("age"))
                << std::endl;
        if(it->first=="company")
            root.insert(it,make_pair("conditions",attached_node));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, once I iterate reversely via:

```
    for(auto it=root.rbegin();it!=root.rend();++it)
```

I face with an error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::insert(boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::reverse_iterator&, std::pair<const char*, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >)’
     root.insert(it,make_pair("conditions",attached_node));
                                                         ^
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the insert function doesn't take a reverse iterator.

Use [`base()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) to get it:

[image]

```
root.insert(it.base(), make_pair("conditions",attached_node));
```

But **BOOM**: *inifite loop*! You're modifying while iterating. This is <strike>never</strike> rarely a good idea. Though [iterator and reference stability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) prevent this from actually being Undefined Behaviour, in your case you happen to get keep finding the same `company` node "next" in the loop.

That's a preventable bug.

Don't be tempted to "just throw in a `break;` statement".

Fix it the mindful way: Use [CQS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23deb57d6a3e8754)</kbd>**

```
auto it = find_by_key(root.rbegin(), root.rend(), "company");
if (it != root.rend())
    root.insert(it.base(), make_pair("conditions",attached_node));
```

See how much cleaner that became! `find_by_key` is a trivial wrapper around a standard algorithm:

```
template <typename It>
It find_by_key(It f, It l, std::string const& key) {
    return std::find_if(f, l, [&](auto const& pair) {
        //std::cout << pair.first << ": " << pair.second.get("age", "?") << "\n";
        return pair.first == key;
    });
}
```

If you can do without the debug possibility, it's more efficient to use the `ptree` interface:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef21a27df2ee09c3)</kbd>**

```
auto it = root.equal_range("company").second;
if (it != root.not_found())
    root.insert(root.to_iterator(it), make_pair("conditions",attached_node));
```

---

In other words:

> #### Algorithms, algorithms, algorithms.

For inspiration: ["Never write a raw for loop" - Sean Parent](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning)

[image]